# Is node.js excessive for non real time web sites/apps?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I just today heard about node.js, being new to web development. After hours of research, I finally found [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/node-js-is-the-new-black/) that explained clearly to me what node.js did.

I'm in the process of creating a reviews website. Content will mostly be stored and retrieved from a database, with an emphasis on user search for finding reviews. There will be no real time content anywhere. It seems like the main purpose of node.js is to create web servers that can serve real time applications by using a persistent socket connection, something that my proposed website/app does not do.

I know that PHP will serve me just fine in what I need, but my question is, are there any other benefits that node.js can give to non real-time web sites/applications?

Comment: What background do you have? PHP, C, JavaScript, ...? Do you expect your site being high-volume? Do you plan a Single-Page-Webapp or a classic one?

Comment: My background is in C++/Java. I do expect it to be high-volume, at least that is my hope. I plan for it to be a classic site.

Comment: To anyone who finds this later, the article is somewhat out of date. Websockets are here, not the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js isn't just for writing real time websites. It also provides a common language between server and client code, offers hundreds of modules — see [NPM](https://npmjs.org/) — and is moving at a good rate.

At the end of the day, it boils down to what you're comfortable with. If you're happy using PHP and see no reason why you'd ever want to have real time aspects, then use PHP. If you're not comfortable with JS and async paradigms, then stick with PHP. If you love JavaScript, there is no reason not to use it.